# Integrating GeoServer Map layer to Grafana Geomap

Tags: geoserver, tile-map-service, xyz-tiles

I am a software integrator and new to GeoServer. I have created a map layer in GeoServer and can view it via the following URL:

http://localhost:8585/geoserver/gwc/demo/OSM_hungary?gridSet=Hungary&format=image/png

I want to get it URL in the form with XYZ tile server(i.e.) URL ends with /{z}/{x}/{y}.png so that I can link it to the grafana geomap dashboard.

Required URL format: http://localhost:8585/geoserver/..../{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Is it possible to generate this URL using any of the web map services in GeoServer?